# How can i search through array of strings in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

```
Mydocument =         (
                        {
                "allow_signoff" = N;
                "chart_no" = PT00027045;
                "checked_note" = "";
                "doc_path" = "20130227\\imsgo_ad.jpg";
                "doc_type" = 3;
                "document_subcat" = "CONSULTATION REPORT";
                firstname = Pangchia;
                "forwardto_emp" =                 (
                    "Andrews, Engelyn",
                    "Anup12, Gau12",
                    "Anup12, Gauri12",
                    "Atienza, Marivic",
                    "Birdsong, Rovonia",
                    "Bliatout, Bobby"
                );
                "forwardto_title" =                 (
                    Administrator,
                    Biller,
                    CEO,
                    Counselor,
                    CPHW,
                    "Front Desk",
                    "Medical Assistant",
                    "Nurse Practitioner"
                );
```

i'm getting this response from web service. Now i'm storing the data from forwardto_emp into an NSMutableArray. But when i use that array my app crashes. I was not able to take its count or use objectAtIndex method with the array.

Comment: Try using `NSPredicate`

Comment: What happens if you try to NSLog your forwardto_emp array? You say that you're getting the response from a web service- how are you reading that response in the first place? Post some code of what you're doing now so that we can see where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am writing simple code for how to search value from array by `NSPredicate`.

```
NSPredicate *predicateSearch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", putValueForSearch]; // Here in your case you need to write value of array that you want to search
NSArray *resultSearchArray = [myArrayName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateSearch];
NSLog(@"%@", resultSearchArray); // "myArrayName" is array that your want to search value from it.
```

Change above code as per your requirement.

Comment: have a look at question again i edited it.

Comment: how to store you forwardto_emp data to array ?

Comment: arr_forwardToEmp = [[arr_documents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"forwardto_emp"];
arr_document is storing the whole response. And arr_forwardToEmp is storing the array which i shown.